# How to mathematically derive the pressure contribution to drag force over a with viscous contribution determined?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, differential-equations, viscosity, navier-stokes

I've looked in a lot of books on how it would be possible to derive the drag force over a sphere using PDEs. I've also learned in my fluid dynamics class how to derive the drag force of a rotating sphere in steady flow but we didn't use PDEs. Instead, we used superposition and potential flow to find a solution.

I've been able to derive half of the problem mathematically determining that FD
is $4πμUR^2$ but I can't derive the pressure contribution as substituting my $\frac{δu}{δr}$ into stokes law results in the pressure contribution being equivalent to zero.

I obtained the equation $ -r^2 \frac{dp}{dr}+\mu (r^2\frac{du}{dr})=C_1$ where I obtained that $C_1 = \mu UR$. If just substitute and integrate to get $p$ i will just get $0$. Is there any assumption or other equation that I should use instead?

Comment: See solution of this problem in Transport Phenomena by Bird et al.